# Unir tablas a través de una misma columna (POWERBI)

Tags: powerbi

Tengo dos tablas con las mismas columnas y quiero hacer una unión entre ellas, de tal forma que consiga una tabla en la que tenga únicamente los products_id que coincidan entre ellas.

Simplificando mi caso y **omitiendo el resto de columnas**:

**TABLE 1**

Product_id

1

2

2

2

**TABLE 2**

Product_id

1

1

3

4

El resultado que quiero alcanzar en este caso sería el siguiente:

**TOTAL TABLE**

Product_id

1

1

1

2

2

2

He intentado utilizar las funciones de UNION e INTERSECT, pero con ninguna he obtenido el resultado que esperaba. Soy nuevo en lenguaje DAX así que es posible que lo haya hecho mal. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás en Power BI puedes hacerlo en Power Query. Solo debes hacer click en `Transformar datos` en la cinta de Inicio debes utilizar la opción de "Anexar consultas" para unir las 3 tablas de forma vertical.

[Acá](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/anexar-consultas-power-query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a) puedes encontrar información de cómo hacerlo.